# gazebo URDF collapsing - need tips for inertia (solved)

Tags: urdf, ros-melodic, ros-control, gazebo-plugins, robot-description

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I have a problem with gazebo spawning the links of my URDF model not correctly.

**So figured out that it is still a problem with the inertia.**

-I tried to fix it but could not make it stable. When adding link by link after the 5th part everything is collapsing.  I removed the big table from the URDF, than there was a change but in the end it still collapses.

-I used the inertia calculated by Mashlab and I tried it with the inertia from SolidWorks, but there was no improvement. Using different masses for the links didnt change anything as well.

**Question 1**: should I build the complete testbench in solid works and than use the urdf_exporter? By now I build the URDF link by link...

**Question 2**: If I change the structure of the URDF in Gazebo but leave the old structure in MoveIt, would there be problems with the transformations ?

> **Question 1**: should I build the complete testbench in solid works and
> than use the urdf_exporter? By now I
> build the URDF link by link...

'-->I didnt go that way but: I **reduced fixed Joints** to zero (except base_link). Making assemblies in SolidWorks and using the **inertia from the urdf_exporter** made it nearly stable when spawning. The model is still a little shaky,  I will keep working on that.

ROI3000

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341934/gazebo-urdf-collapsing---need-tips-for-inertia-(solved)/) by [ROI](https://answers.ros.org/users/50983/roi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2020-01-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-20**:
If you've solved this, please post the solution as an answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
so I solved the issue with the collapsing model. It is still a little shaky but I hope that it will improve.

Things I did to solve the Problem:

> Question 1: should I build the complete testbench in solid works and than use the urdf_exporter? By now I build the URDF link by link...

- I had the wrong world origin for the test bench. so I had to move up in z
- And I reduced fixed joints in the URDF: connecting Links in SolidWorks (SW) and than exported them as one single part. And I used the inertial, which were calculated by the urdf_exporter.

By now I only have issues with the controller to use moveit and gazebo!

---

Originally posted by [ROI](https://answers.ros.org/users/50983/roi/) with karma: 36 on 2020-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0